# How to remove all hidden characters except colons, numbers and 'AM' or 'PM'

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string that has the time in it like this

"6:00:00 AM" or "10:15:00 PM"

I know the string has hidden characters in it so I would like to use a regex to replace all characters except colons, numbers and AM or PM.

not sure if this below works because I have a string comparison check that is still failing.

```
selectedTime = selectedTime.replace(/^\w:\s/g, "");
```

I also tried

```
selectedTime = selectedTime.replace(/[^\w:\s]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex replaces all characters except digit, colon, and AM PM

```
selectedTime = selectedTime.replace(/[^\d:AMP]/gi, "");
```

Here is [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aH6dT0/3)

Comment: I need spaces removed too because there might be hidden spaces

Comment: I'm not sure if there is other data in the string, for the example this should work.

Comment: It should for sure remove any nasty hidden characters

Answer (score 0):

As stated... This replaced everything except numbers (the ^\d part), colon (the ^: part) and AM/PM (the ^AMP part).

selectedTime = selectedTime.replace(/[^\d:AMP]/g,"");

You might also test using https://regex101.com